# Why is this a valid change of variables?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

We have the integral: $$ \int\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+a-1}dx$$ with $a>1$.

Why is $ u = \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{a-1}} $ a valid change of variables to get: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a-1}} \int \frac{1}{u^2+1} du $$

Comment: Are you sure the integral is written properly? Should the denominator be $x^2+1+a-1$? Because that is clearly just $x^2+a$.

Comment: my bad, its correct now.

Comment: Also, why have $\sqrt{(a-1)^2}$, wouldn't that just be $|a-1|=a-1$ if $a>1$?

Comment: ok now it should be correct

Comment: It **isn't**!  With $u= \frac{(x+ 1)^2}{a- 1}$ ($\sqrt{a- 1)^2}= a- 1$ as long as $a\ge 1$ and is not defined otherwise), $du= 2(x+ 1)dx$ and that is missing in your integral.  **If** the problem were $\int\frac{x+ 1}{\sqrt{(x+ 1)^2+ a- 1}}dx$ **then** that substitution would work.

Comment: @Maddude see my edit of the question and make sure this is what is intended.

Comment: @user247327 well, the online integral calculator showed me this change of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$\frac{1}{(x+1)^2+a-1}=\frac{1}{a-1}\frac{1}{(x+1)^2/(a-1)+1}=\frac{1}{a-1}\frac{1}{((x+1)/\sqrt{a-1})^2+1}$$
So letting $u=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{a-1}}$ we have $du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a-1}}dx\implies dx=\sqrt{a-1}du$. So the integral becomes:
$$\int\frac{1}{a-1}\frac{1}{((x+1)/\sqrt{a-1})^2+1}dx=\int\frac{1}{a-1}\frac{1}{u^2+1}\sqrt{a-1}du$$
which produces the result. This can then be easily solved by the $\arctan$ integral.

Answer (score 2):

First pull a factor of $(a-1)$ out of the denominator:
$$\int\frac1{(x+1)^2+a-1}\, dx = \int \frac1{(a-1)\left[\frac{(x+1)^2}{a-1} + 1\right]} \, dx$$
Since $a-1$ is a constant, pull it out of the integral:
$$\int \frac1{(a-1)\left[\frac{(x+1)^2}{a-1} + 1\right]} \, dx = \frac1{a-1}\int \frac1{\frac{(x+1)^2}{a-1} + 1} \, dx$$
Note that $a-1 = (\sqrt{a-1})^2$, so then we have:
\begin{align*}\frac1{a-1}\int \frac1{\frac{(x+1)^2}{a-1} + 1} \, dx &= \frac1{a-1}\int \frac1{\frac{(x+1)^2}{(\sqrt{a-1})^2} + 1} \, dx\\[0.3cm] &= \frac1{a-1}\int \frac1{\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{a-1}}\right)^2 + 1} \, dx\end{align*}
Now let $u = \dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{a-1}}$.  Note that this means $x = u\sqrt{a-1} - 1$, and so $dx = \sqrt{a-1}\, du$.  So we have:
\begin{align*}
\frac1{a-1}\int \frac1{\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{a-1}}\right)^2 + 1} \, dx &= \frac1{a-1}\int \frac1{u^2 + 1} \, \sqrt{a-1} \, du\\[0.3cm]
&= \frac{\sqrt{a-1}}{(\sqrt{a-1})^2} \int\frac1{u^2+1}\,du\\[0.3cm]
&= \frac1{\sqrt{a-1}} \int\frac1{u^2+1}\,du
\end{align*}